# using Bundle Object as the parameter or as the instance class

Tags: java, android

is better to use the **Bundle** Object as the parameter **OR** it is better to use the **Bundle** Object as the instance class?

Is there a specific differences between these two methods:

**1)**

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceView){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceView);
.........
}}
```

**2)**

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(){
Bundle savedInstanceView = new Bundle();    
super.onCreate(savedInstanceView);
    .........
    }}
```

If I use the second method, is it a good action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the second one - the signature of the the method being `@Override`n must remain the same.

Furthermore, even if you do not use the `Bundle` passed to 'onCreate()`, this object is not necessarily empty - it is automatically populated by the system in`onSavedInstanceState()`with the data of UI widgets (e.g. text in`EditText`)

Bottom line: keep methods signature as it is, and don't forget to call to `super.onCreate()` passing the `Bundle`parameter.